# Mongoose / MongoDB: Reference value from different Model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have two Mongoose models or MongoDB collections:

```
// Collection: students

{
  student:student,
  email:email
}

// Collection: tutors

{
  tutor:tutor,
  student:student
}
```

Now how would I achieve referring to the students email of the student collection inside my tutor collection? E.g.:

```
// Pseudo-Model

{
  tutor:tutor,
  studentEmail:students.student.email
}
```

In other words I want to **get the email of a particular student** right in my Tutor Collection (or Mongoose Model, I dont care where to code this reference).

Is this possible with Mongoose or MongoDB?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new document? Why not just have have a student document embedded in your tutor document?

Comment: Think of it like this. I have 100 Students, whose Name can change when they marry, this is why I want to refer to them by their email, which never changes in this scenario. Also other departments of the University (lets say Student services) are needing a Students Collection, but don't need the Tutor collection. I do not want to end up with redundancies, or is a MapReduce the way to go if I need a ForeignKey RelationShip?